# How to A/B split test a Wordpress header content?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ab-testing

On this [site](https://visitshenandoahcounty.com), I have in my header.php file, the code below. 
Embedded so that it shows up right under my menu on all my pages.
(*Note.* It is set to  display: none; on the homepage.)

```
<div id="widget-container-1450"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function() {
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 script.async = 'true';
 script.src = "https://admin.bookdirect.net/hs4/widgets/1450.js?widget_element=widget-container-1450";
 document.body.appendChild(script);
 })();
</script>
```

I would like to split test this and another variation of this.

There are plugins that might do the job, NEILO A/B TESTING, AB Press Optimizer etc, but they are pretty expensive and I'm not 100% sure they will work.

I know some code and can figure stuff out. so any suggestions or ideas would be helpful and appreciated.

Thanks

Sparkie the DOG

Comment: Google analytics has this functionality https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments

Comment: You could try google optimize as well. I am not sure about the use with this JS, but it is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys.

I did end up using Google optimize.
https://optimize.google.com/
It worked pretty well, although it took a little bit to get the hang of it.

Thanks again.